# How can we update the existing image in firebase cloud storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I used `react-native-firebase` lib in my RN App

and I use Firebase Storage to save image in the cloud so it's work very well but

In profile screen and I have an **Edit function** that replaces the old image with a new one but it's just adding a new image to Firebase Cloud Storage not replaced it

so there any way for just replacing old with new?

because I don't want to increase my storage when users change his image profile

[image: S]

here is my function that's save new image profile

```
 EditImg = async () => {
    const {uid, avatar} = this.state;
    let providerRef = database().ref(`Providers/users/${uid}`);
    const path = 'Avatar_' + new Date().getTime() + '.jpg';
    const ref = storage().ref(`providers/${uid}/providerGalary/${path}`);
    await ref.putFile(avatar).then(() => {
      ref.getDownloadURL().then(
        img => {
          console.log('img', img);
          providerRef
            .update({
              avatar: img,
            })
            .then(() => console.log('saved to Db Successfully'));
        },
        error => console.log(error),
      );

    });
  };
```

Comment: `const path = 'Avatar_' + new Date().getTime() + '.jpg';` that will make a new name everytime. If you don't want that, change it to be a fixed name.

Comment: Ouch, i forget this thing, Thank u :')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
const path =  'Avatar_' + new Date().getTime() + '.jpg';
    const ref = storage().ref(`providers/${uid}/providerGalary/${path}`);
    await ref.putFile(avatar).then(() => {
```

Into this:

```
const path =  'Avatar_' + uid + '.jpg';
    const ref = storage().ref(`providers/${uid}/providerGalary/${path}`);
    await ref.putFile(avatar).then(() => {
```

Use the `uid` instead of new `Date`, since the `uid` will stay the same thus you will be able to replace the image instead of adding a new one